# Problem with http.get and connection time out Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a problem with a flutter project

I will get a json on my server running on the port 8080. In the route `/weather/Paris`.

So I do on my weather.dart

```
...
  String? parisW;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getInfoCity("Paris");
    super.initState();
  }
...
Text(parisW.toString()),
...
  void getInfoCity(String city) async {
    if (global.ipAddress == null) {
      return;
    } else {
      var reponse = await http.get(
          Uri.parse('https://' + global.ipAddress + ':8080/weather/$city'));
      print(reponse.body);
      if (reponse.statusCode != 200) return;
      setState() {
        parisW = reponse.body;
      }
    }
  }
```

Both of the ip and the route is correct

Answer (score 0):

Seems strange to a have the port `8080` using the `HTTPS` scheme. This is usually the port `8083` but of course it depends on the server configuration.

Did you try with:
`'http://' + global.ipAddress + ':8080/weather/$city'`? (without the secure protocol)